# Glossaries include symbol from other glossary in name

Tags: glossaries

I have a glossary entry which defines a symbol

```
\newglossaryentry{nc:line:num}{
    name=cache lines,
    symbol=\ensuremath{\#l},
    description=number of lines in cache}
```

and want to use its `symbol` in another entry inside a second glossary. Therefore I try:

```
\newglossaryentry{cache:swayassociative}{
    name={\glsentrysymbol{nc:line:num}-way associative},
    description={\nopostdesc},
    parent={cache},
    see={nc:line:num}
```

however this puts the code into the output, rather than the actual symbol.

[image: alignment and text are off]

As a bonus I am unsure how to properly right align the numbers and place the "see XXX" text properly, so that they don't overlap. (I am using the `mcolalttreegroup` style).

P.S.: I am trying to use glossaries for an index here, maybe it is not quite the right tool for the job, but since I actually use it for real glossaries as well, I thought it would not hurt to use a tool I am fairly familiar with (considering I am a novice and have no experience with makeidx).

P.P.S.: I used the time to take a deeper look at makeidx, and noticed that entries like `\ensuremath{n}-way associative` are troublesome, and the short documentation of tha package hints that i should stick with glossaries wich has extra sort keys for such cases

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package option `sanitize=none` should fix this. You can then modify the glossary style to change the position of the numbers, and other things (3.6 of the 'Documented Code' and 16.2 of the user manual):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[sanitize=none]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{nc:line:num}{
    name=cache lines,
    symbol=\ensuremath{\#l},
    description=number of lines in cache}
\newglossaryentry{cache:swayassociative}{
    name={\glsentrysymbol{nc:line:num}-way associative},
    description={\nopostdesc},
    parent={cache},
    see={nc:line:num}}
\makeglossaries%

\newglossarystyle{indexGlossaryStyle}{
    \glossarystyle{mcolalttreegroup}
    \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \renewcommand{\glspostdescription}{\hspace*{\fill}see}}

\begin{document}
    \printglossary[style=indexGlossaryStyle]%
    \clearpage%
    nc:line:num glossary entry '\gls{nc:line:num}`
    \clearpage%
    cache:swayassociative glossary entry '\gls{cache:swayassociative}`
\end{document}
```

Although, maybe some investment in a indexing package rather than a glossary would be more suitable.

Comment: thank you, it works like a charm, i still have to figure out the downside (otherwise it would be tha packages default setting, right?). What indexing package would you recommend, I have trouble typesetting something in math mode with `makeidx` and I thought `glossaries` looks like a little more work, but feels a lot more powerfull...

Comment: @ted: I have not used indexing much, but I have tried multind mainly because I wanted a few different indices. The downside for my use of glossaries is that I use entries so much that I would want to be selective about which entries are listed in an 'index'. If you are using entries rarely then maybe it would be suitable for you.

Comment: I cheat a little, I type them out usually and just use the `glossaries` commands where I want a reference, that way I dont clutter my glossary