# glossaries and phantom

Tags: glossaries

I am trying to align my symbols in a glossary with `\phantom`. However when I try to do so, I get the following error (`line 10` is the line where the definition of  `nc:line:num` ends(closing brace)):

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 10.
```

near MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[sanitize=none]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries%

\newglossaryentry{nc:line:num}{
    name=thing,
    symbol=\ensuremath{\phantom{\#}l},
    description=other thing}
\newglossaryentry{nc}{
    name=thingy,
    symbol=\ensuremath{\#l},
    description=something}


\usepackage{glossary-mcols} 


\begin{document}
    \printglossary[style=altlong4col]
    asd
    \clearpage%
    nc:line:num glossary entry '\gls{nc:line:num}` \gls{nc}
\end{document}
```

**Background:**
I have symbols that usually exist in two versions as `symbol` and as `#symbol`, therefore i would like to align in the following way:

```
 symbol
#symbol
 other
#other
```

rather than

```
symbol
#symbol
other
#other
```

**Note:** `sanitize=none` is used because I reference entries from another glossary, see [this awnser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116419/19326)

Comment: maybe a different phrasing of the title would make this more "attractive", something like "aligning glossary entries with a flag character to the left of some entries".  (too many words, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: thank you for your input. Luckily I already have the awnser and unfortunately I fail to see a catchy phrase, but I will try to keep this in midn for new questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry for `symbol` is written to the file `.glo`. `\phantom` or `\hphantom` is fragile and breaks. `\protect` needs to be used:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[sanitize=none]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries%

\newglossaryentry{nc:line:num}{
    name=thing,
    symbol=\ensuremath{\protect\hphantom{\#}l},
    description=other thing}
\newglossaryentry{nc}{
    name=thingy,
    symbol=\ensuremath{\#l},
    description=something}  


\usepackage{glossary-mcols}


\begin{document}
    \printglossary[style=altlong4col]
    asd
    \clearpage%
    nc:line:num glossary entry '\gls{nc:line:num}` \gls{nc}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: for those who are as unfamiliar with latex as i am, looke [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/19326) to see what protect and fragile are about